# How to get the sum of values from one column with the conditional of another column

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, for-loop

For the sample data shown in the below image:

[image]

How can I get the number of similar items that occur within one column, with the conditional the customer_id is the same?

```
ls=[]
for i in data['customer_id']:
    sum=0
    for j in data['category']:    
        if i == j[0]:
            sum+=j[1]
    ls.append(sum)
```

In short:

```
[food and fruit, vegetable, bakery and bread, cookies snacks or candies, seafoods and meat] 
customer_id[0] = [4,9,5,1,0]
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please don't add data or code as images. Instead use plain text or better yet, provide a piece of code that constructs the dataframe. This will make it much more likely that someone is quickly able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is loaded into a pandas dataframe, you can use:

```
# Sample data
labels = ["a", "b", "c", "a, b, c", "b, c"]
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "customer_id": [0, 1]*10,
    "category": [labels[np.random.randint(0,len(labels ))] for i in range(20)]
})

# Count per group and pivot the rows to columns
df.groupby(['customer_id', 'category']).size().reset_index().pivot_table(
    0, ['customer_id'], 'category').fillna(0).rename_axis(
        None, axis=1).reset_index()
```

output:

```
    customer_id   a      a, b, c      b      b, c      c
0   0           2.0          1.0    1.0       5.0    1.0
1   1           2.0          0.0    4.0       1.0    3.0
```